# Message Id (PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID_W_TAG) Not Available in Event Handler After Sending An Email

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an instance of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application` and I add `itemSendHandler` to the `Application.itemSend`

```
Application.itemSend += itemSendHandler
```

I'm assuming inside the `itemSendHandler`, the email should already be sent and a Message Id should exist for the email. Yet the following code produces a null `messageId`:

```
private void itemSendEventHandler(object sentItem, ref bool Cancel)
}
    string PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID_W_TAG = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F";
    PropertyAccessor propertyAccessor = ((MailItem)sentItem).PropertyAccessor;
    // This is null? Why?
    string messageId = (string)propertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID_W_TAG);
    ThisAddIn.attemptToReleaseComObject(propertyAccessor);   
{
```

But when I inspect the sent item immediately afterwards, through the code or through a tool (like OutlookSpy or MFCMAPI), the property exists. Why is `messageId` null during the send event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the message first before accessing that property. Even then, `PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID` might not be accessible in the cached mode - Outlook will not synchronize the item in the Sent Items folder with its online replica for the performance reasons, and only the online version of the message will have that property. You can open that message in the online mode using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language) by using the `MAPI_NO_CACHE` flag, but there is no way to do that in OOM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to get the `PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID` reliably, even if it's some time into the future?

Comment: Or by having the profile in the online mode to begin with.